# "Позаботьтесь... сегодня(,) и завтра вам не придётся..." —являются ли сказуемые однородными?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены

> Позаботьтесь о корректном рационе сегодня и завтра вам не придётся идти к гастроэнтерологу.

Являются ли сказуемые однородными?
И, собственно, нужна ли запятая между частями?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Позаботьтесь** о корректном рационе сегодня,  и завтра вам **не придётся идти** к гастроэнтерологу.

**Здесь нет однородных сказуемых,** это сложносочиненное предложение (ССП), запятая ставится.

**Оба предложения односоставные**. Первое предложение определенно-личное, а второе безличное.

В первом предложении сказуемое выражено **повелительной формой глагола.**

Во втором предложении составное глагольное сказуемое ***придется идти***, связка выражена глагольной формой 
***придется*** с модальным значением.

**Примечание**

Основной знак – **запятая**.

**Тире** в ССП является неосновным знаком, в данном случае тире может **подчеркивать**  взаимообусловленность частей предложения.

Comment: Вот это ответ полный!

Answer (score 5):

> Нужна ли запятая между частями?

Лучше поставить тире:

***Позаботьтесь о корректном рационе сегодня — и завтра вам не придётся идти к гастроэнтерологу.***

Из [**ПАС**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133):

> **§ 114.** Между частями сложносочиненного предложения ставится тире, если вторая часть предложения заключает в себе значение результата,
>   следствия...

Comment: Ответ полезный (+1), но неполный. Юлия спрашивает, являются ли сказуемые однородными. Нужно объяснить, почему это ССП, а не простое.

Comment: _М_Г: Ответ полезный (+1), но неполный. Юлия спрашивает, являются ли сказуемые однородными._ === Хоть я прямо об этом и не написал, всё же из моего ответа явно (как мне кажется) следует, что сказуемые в этом предложении не однородны. А вот почему неоднородны? Самый простой ответ — сослаться на это: "Правило гласит, что однородные члены отвечают на один и тот же вопрос…

Подробнее: https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/odnorodnye-skazuemye-primery-4-klass.html#ixzz5cseaw5UK ". Можно ли поставить одинаковые вопросы к имеющимся в рассматриваемом предложении сказуемым?